# Find distance of drag in D3

Tags: d3.js

I've got a set of D3 elements (they happen to be text nodes, but I think it doesn't matter what kind) that I've attached drag behavior to:

```
        paragraphs.enter().append("text")
            .text(function (d, i) { return d })
            .attr("x", function (d, i) { return (i + 1) * 32 })
            .attr("y", function (d, i) { return (i + 1) * 16 })
            .attr("fill", color)
            .call(d3.drag()
                .on("start", dragstarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragended))
```

I'd like the drag behavior to be aware of how far the user has dragged since the dragstart.  Currently, I add an `attr` in `dragstarted` which stamps the initial position, then during `dragged` check for current position and calculate it that way.

**Is there a way to find the distance dragged since the drag `start` without calculating it, simply from the drag events directly?**  I've looked at `dx`/`dy`, but they seem to calculate only since the last drag event, so the value is always in the low single digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag), those are the fields exposed by the event object during the drag event:

> - target - the associated drag behavior.
> - type - the string “start”, “drag” or “end”; see drag.on.
> - subject - the drag subject, defined by drag.subject.
> - x - the new x-coordinate of the subject; see drag.container.
> - y - the new y-coordinate of the subject; see drag.container.
> - dx - the change in x-coordinate since the previous drag event.
> - dy - the change in y-coordinate since the previous drag event.
> - identifier - the string “mouse”, or a numeric touch identifier.
> - active - the number of currently active drag gestures (on start and end, not including this one).
> - sourceEvent - the underlying input event, such as mousemove or touchmove.

As you can see, **none of them** holds the value that you are looking for.

However, there is a simple solution, which may not suit you since you clearly stated **"without calculating it"**.

The solution involves getting the position at the "start" listener and comparing it with the position at the "end" listener:

```
d3.drag().on("start", function(d) {
    d.startX = d.x;
    d.startY = d.y;
}).on("drag", function(d) {
    d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
}).on("end", function(d) {
    console.log("x distance: " + (d.x - d.startX))
    console.log("y distance: " + (d.y - d.startY))
})
```

This is a simple demo, drag the circle around:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var circle = svg.append("circle")
  .datum({
    x: 150,
    y: 75
  })
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y
  })
  .attr("r", 10)
  .attr("fill", "teal");

circle.call(d3.drag().on("start", function(d) {
  d.startX = d.x;
  d.startY = d.y;
}).on("drag", function(d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
}).on("end", function(d) {
  console.log("x distance: " + (d.x - d.startX))
  console.log("y distance: " + (d.y - d.startY))
}))
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 25% !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Again: I'm aware that you said *"no calculation"*, but since there is no native property for what you want I thought it would be worth showing how simple it is doing the calculation.